# How to store value pairs in Rails 4 (postgres db)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I'm trying to store two types of product identifications together, one for each product color for each product.

I want to do this without creating another table, just by storing a set of id pairs. My form looks like this:

[image]

How can i submit and store this data in a consistent way? Is Hstore a good alternative for this?

Comment: Hstore stores everything as a string. That may have a serious impact on other parts of your business logic, such as indexing and referential integrity maintenance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don’t you want to create another table? Your data model seems to necessitate it. I would recommend avoiding database-specific solutions when a Rails-based one (adding another model) would be more universal and is trivially supported.

Comment: Agree. This is also how i solved it. Sorry for wasting your time. :-/

Comment: Aww, no problem. Perhaps you were feeling reluctant to create a whole new model, I’ve felt that same sort of hesitation, but it’s best to let those pressures tell you something rather than fighting them.